# How can we set the memory of array using cstring packgae functions in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, c-strings

i want to allocate a number to whole array using memset function of cstring class.bbut it only works for 0,if i provide any other value to the function memset it randomly assigns a large integer no to the memory of array.

```
memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
```

for this it works fine each slot in array i assigned 0 value;
but if i do this

```
memset(arr,1 or any other no,sizeof(arr));
```

for this it alots a random larger integer value to each slot  of array;
pls explain why is it happening like this.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of both cases. [ask] should help you with creating a well answerable question.

Comment: It would not be an array of other things than `char`, would it? That is one of the questions which I only have to ask because there is no MRE.

Comment: The random numbers are 257 or 16843009 in case of memset to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `std::fill`.

`std::memset` is a primitive function. It sets bytes in memory, not values. The value `257` in binary is `0x0101`. That shows you what happened: both bytes were set to `0x01`.

Since you want to set the value to `0x0001`, it clearly is not possible to do so with `std::memset`, since it sets everything to the same byte value. `std::fill` on the other hand understands types, and will convert the value you give it. So it can convert `1` to `1.0f` when filling an array of floats.

Comment: Looks like you rely on what I only consider speculation of missing details...